# Heroku skips pruning devDependencies when NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION is 'false'

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, heroku, webpack

I'm trying to deploy a JS/node/express/webpack application to Heroku.

I need Heroku to install my devDependencies because it includes webpack, which is necessary to build the client-side files of my project.

However, I cannot get Heroku to read my devDependencies.

I have read everywhere that setting **NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION = 'false'** will fix this, but it does not.
Here are my config vars for my Heroku build (taken from the build log):

```
NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false    // I set this from both the heroku-cli and the web ui
NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
NODE_VERBOSE=false
NODE_ENV=production
NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
```

Then the logs go on to say:

```
-----> Pruning devDependencies
       Skipping because NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION is 'false'
```

Isn't the desired behavior that devDependencies will be install when this var is set to false?

Comment: "Pruning" does not mean "installing". It's sort of the opposite. Heroku [installs `devDependencies` out of the box](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#package-installation). Then, if you're running a production build, it prunes (removes) them. The word [comes from gardening](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pruning). So I'm not clear what your question is. Please [edit] your question and show us your `package.json`.

Comment: Hey Chris

I was having trouble getting my webpack plugin 'copy-webpack-plugin' to work. Not exactly sure what the problem was, but clearing my webpack's 'build-target' location (e.g. /dist), as well as deleting my package-lock.json and node_modules files (with a subsequent run of 'npm i' in the terminal) seemed to fix the issue. In other words, I just needed to turn it off and back on